# Open bootstrap dropdown failed on ng-grid/ui-grid

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

How to open bootstrap-dropdown when i click on cell within ng-grid ?
I can open it only partially.

`Here's` [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JXNkgrlC7X5YVQR8g8jG?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this to your CSS:

```
.ngCell {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

which allows the ngCell to display the drop down like you want. The issue that I'm having is getting the drop down on a lower cell to appear over the ngGrid footer rather than increasing the size of the scroll bar.

Answer (score -2):

This CSS worked for me so something in this direction will hopefully work for you

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: fixed;
display: block;
margin: 22px;
top: auto;
left: 0px;
padding: 0px;
```